# php document that checks errors of an array of predefined passwords

Tags: php

In my program, I have to check for reasons why the passwords are failing. The length, if whitespace is present, if there is a number, a lowercase letter, an uppercase letter, and a non-alphanumeric symbol. I am getting all of the tests except length of the password correctly errored. i've been trying to look around everywere without copy and pasting someones work, and tried different methods with the same results. I am new to php so it might be a syntax misuse or something but here is my code.

```
$password=array("fajsldkL^","falsd L8&","JLKJOIH9*","fjdsllsk9*","fjasldkfK8","fjl*9K","djflsK909*dkK","fdkjslK9*","fjslaKLK98*","fjasdlkKJ87*");
$goodPassword="fjasdlkKJ87*";
$count=0; // helps manually cycle through the array because i dont know how else to with foreach

foreach($password as $goodPassword)
{
  $length=array_map('strlen', $password); //supposed to get length of the array element
  $invalidLength=true;
  $whitespace=false;
  $numerical=false;
  $lower=false;
  $upper=false;
  $special=false;

  echo "Your password: $password[$count] </br>";
  $count++;

  if ($length>=8 && $length<=16) //problem area
      $invalidLength=false;
  if (preg_match("/\s/", $goodPassword) ==1)
      $whitespace=true;
  if (preg_match("/[0-9]/", $goodPassword) ==0)
      $numerical=true;
  if (preg_match("/[a-z]/", $goodPassword) ==0)
      $lower=true;
  if (preg_match("/[A-Z]/", $goodPassword) ==0)
      $upper=true;
  if (preg_match("/\W/", $goodPassword) ==0)
      $special=true;

  if ($invalidLength==true)
      echo "Password is not between 8 and 16 characters. </br>";
  if ($whitespace==true)
      echo "Password should not have any spaces. </br>";
  if ($numerical==true)
      echo "Password needs at least 1 number. </br>";
  if ($lower==true)
      echo "Password needs at least 1 lowercase letter. </br>";
  if ($upper==true)
      echo "Password needs at least 1 uppercase letter. </br>";
  if ($special==true)
      echo "Password needs at least 1 none alphanumerical symobl. </br>";

  if ($invalidLength==false && $whitespace==false && $numerical==false && $lower==false && $upper==false && $special==false)
      echo "Password is good. </br>";
}
```

fjl*9K is supposed to fail the length test but it does not, if I flip things around they either all fail, or this element and the ones after it do not fail. Thanks much for any help. I am going to feel so dumb if its just a simple logical error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$passwords = array('fajsldkL^', 'falsd L8&', 'JLKJOIH9*', 'fjdsllsk9*', 'fjasldkfK8', 'fjl*9K', 'djflsK909*dkK', 'fdkjslK9*', 'fjslaKLK98*', 'fjasdlkKJ87*'); // lets name this plural since it contains lots of passwords. also use single quote for literal strings

// $goodPassword = 'fjasdlkKJ87*';  // lets remove this since we will use the loop
// $count        = 0; // lets remove this

foreach ($passwords as $password) { // notice the plural and singular, its how you use foreach, its readable that way
    $length        = strlen($password); // this is the correct way
    $invalidLength = true;
    $whitespace    = false;
    $numerical     = false;
    $lower         = false;
    $upper         = false;
    $special       = false;

    echo "Your password: $password </br>"; // use the variable $password also use double quote for parsed string since its the alias of the array's item
    // $count++; //let remove this, we dont need this

    if ($length >= 8 && $length <= 16) //problem area
    {
        $invalidLength = false;
    }

    if (preg_match("/\s/", $password) == 1) {
        $whitespace = true;
    }

    if (preg_match("/[0-9]/", $password) == 0) {
        $numerical = true;
    }

    if (preg_match("/[a-z]/", $password) == 0) {
        $lower = true;
    }

    if (preg_match("/[A-Z]/", $password) == 0) {
        $upper = true;
    }

    if (preg_match("/\W/", $password) == 0) {
        $special = true;
    }

    if ($invalidLength == true) {
        echo 'Password is not between 8 and 16 characters. </br>';
    }

    if ($whitespace == true) {
        echo 'Password should not have any spaces. </br>';
    }

    if ($numerical == true) {
        echo 'Password needs at least 1 number. </br>';
    }

    if ($lower == true) {
        echo 'Password needs at least 1 lowercase letter. </br>';
    }

    if ($upper == true) {
        echo 'Password needs at least 1 uppercase letter. </br>';
    }

    if ($special == true) {
        echo 'Password needs at least 1 none alphanumerical symobl. </br>';
    }

    if ($invalidLength == false && $whitespace == false && $numerical == false && $lower == false && $upper == false && $special == false) {
        echo 'Password is good. </br>';
    }

}
```

You can also write it this way:

```
$passwords = array('fajsldkL^', 'falsd L8&', 'JLKJOIH9*', 'fjdsllsk9*', 'fjasldkfK8', 'fjl*9K', 'djflsK909*dkK', 'fdkjslK9*', 'fjslaKLK98*', 'fjasdlkKJ87*');

foreach ($passwords as $password) {
    echo "</br>Your password: $password</br>";

    $invalid_len     = false;
    $with_space      = false;
    $without_num     = false;
    $without_lower   = false;
    $without_upper   = false;
    $without_special = false;

    $length = strlen($password);

    if ($length < 8 || $length > 16) {
        $invalid_len = true;
        echo 'Password is not between 8 and 16 characters.</br>';
    }

    if (preg_match("/\s/", $password) == 1) {
        $with_space = true;
        echo 'Password should not have any spaces.</br>';
    }

    if (preg_match("/[0-9]/", $password) == 0) {
        $without_num = true;
        echo 'Password needs at least 1 number.</br>';
    }

    if (preg_match("/[a-z]/", $password) == 0) {
        $without_num = true;
        echo 'Password needs at least 1 lowercase letter.</br>';
    }

    if (preg_match("/[A-Z]/", $password) == 0) {
        $without_upper = true;
        echo 'Password needs at least 1 uppercase letter.</br>';
    }

    if (preg_match("/\W/", $password) == 0) {
        $without_special = true;
        echo 'Password needs at least 1 none alphabumerical symbol.</br>';
    }

    if ($invalid_len == false && $with_space == false && $without_num == false && $without_num == false && $without_upper == false && $without_special == false) {
        echo 'Password is good.</br>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, Thank you much. i guess i should have actually looked up what foreach did (I was frazzled because i didn't understand where $password was coming from in your second example). It makes much more sense now. i saw it in some guys example and tried to make it my own. didnt work out too great but now i understand it better. made things so much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Write your code as below:-

```
$password=array("fajsldkL^","falsd L8&","JLKJOIH9*","fjdsllsk9*","fjasldkfK8","fjl*9K","djflsK909*dkK","fdkjslK9*","fjslaKLK98*","fjasdlkKJ87*");
$goodPassword="fjasdlkKJ87*";
// $count=0; // You don't need to use count

foreach($password as $goodPassword)
{
  // Here is wrong. strlen is used to count lenth of string. Here $password is array
  //$length=array_map('strlen', $password); // Write $goodPassword Here
  // Write your variable as below:-
  $length = strlen($goodPassword);
  $invalidLength=true;
  $whitespace=false;
  $numerical=false;
  $lower=false;
  $upper=false;
  $special=false;
  // Write $goodPassword here
  echo "Your password: $goodPassword </br>";
  // $count++; // No need here

  if ($length>=8 && $length<=16) //problem area
      $invalidLength=false;
  if (preg_match("/\s/", $goodPassword) ==1)
      $whitespace=true;
  if (preg_match("/[0-9]/", $goodPassword) ==0)
      $numerical=true;
  if (preg_match("/[a-z]/", $goodPassword) ==0)
      $lower=true;
  if (preg_match("/[A-Z]/", $goodPassword) ==0)
      $upper=true;
  if (preg_match("/\W/", $goodPassword) ==0)
      $special=true;

  if ($invalidLength==true)
      echo "Password is not between 8 and 16 characters. </br>";
  if ($whitespace==true)
      echo "Password should not have any spaces. </br>";
  if ($numerical==true)
      echo "Password needs at least 1 number. </br>";
  if ($lower==true)
      echo "Password needs at least 1 lowercase letter. </br>";
  if ($upper==true)
      echo "Password needs at least 1 uppercase letter. </br>";
  if ($special==true)
      echo "Password needs at least 1 none alphanumerical symobl. </br>";

  if ($invalidLength==false && $whitespace==false && $numerical==false && $lower==false && $upper==false && $special==false)
      // Write $goodPassword in below line:-
      echo "Password $goodPassword is good. </br>";
}
```

Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

In the for loop you used  $length=array_map('strlen', $password); we can use directly as $lenght=strlen($password[$count]);  So the code will be

";
            $count++;

            if ($length>=8 && $length";
            if ($whitespace==true)
                echo "Password should not have any spaces. ";
            if ($numerical==true)
                echo "Password needs at least 1 number. ";
            if ($lower==true)
                echo "Password needs at least 1 lowercase letter. ";
            if ($upper==true)
                echo "Password needs at least 1 uppercase letter. ";
            if ($special==true)
                echo "Password needs at least 1 none alphanumerical symobl. ";

            if ($invalidLength==false && $whitespace==false && $numerical==false && $lower==false && $upper==false && $special==false)
                echo "Password is good. ";
        }
?>